# how to loader 'use client' in react when using module federation between nextjs(host) and react(remote)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I want to migrate legacy react project to next project incrementally. So. I'm trying to set up micro-frontend app, nextjs-ts and react-js. But! remote react app didn't works in nextjs with state..
It works correctly without state.
please, tell me how to solve this problem..! I attaches code example..

```js
// host/page.tsx -- nextjs13, app directory
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const RemoteButton = dynamic(() => import('remote/src/Button'), {
  ssr: false
});
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className="flex flex-col items-center justify-between min-h-screen p-24">
      ss
      <RemoteButton />
    </main>
  );
}
```

```js
// remote/Button.js -- cra, react18
'use client';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Button = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);
  return <div>Button</div>;
};

export default Button;
```

when added 'use client'

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| const Button = () => {
|   const [state, setState] = useState(0);
>   return <div>Button</div>;
| };
| 

Import trace for requested module:
../remote/src/Button.js
```

not

```
You're importing a component that needs useState. It only works in a Client Component but none of its parents are marked with "use client", so they're Server Components by default.
```

how to solve this problem??